# Image_picker plugin for flutter causes build error when running on iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I get this error when running flutter app on iOS simulator.

```
/Users/sirapol/Desktop/FirstCareFrontEnd/care_now_frontend_v1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared_preferences/shared_prefe
    rences.framework: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
    Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings
    are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings
    are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team
    ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

This is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: care_now_frontend_v1
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  provider: ^3.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+1
  path_provider: ^1.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6
  # image_picker: ^0.6.1+4
  # image_picker_modern: ^0.4.12+2
  firebase_storage: ^3.1.1



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  assets:
     - assets/images/

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

This is my info.plist file. I have added the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription as told in the image_picker document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>care_now_frontend_v1</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <string>UIViewController</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <false/>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Library Usage</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Camera Usage</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME} Microphone Usage</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I suspect that the info.plist file is causing the error, but I do not know why. Please help me , thank you.

Comment: here's my suspicion it's either, the version you installed in your pubspec.yaml is not compatible with your flutter so try removing the version, or go to your ios folder and run pod install, and try adding in your signing capabilties a dev team

Comment: change your imagePicker version

Comment: tried that, still got errors

Comment: While running on ios you have to change setting from new build system to legacy build system to build it successfully. I faces this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the main failure is that you have not configured the project's Signing and Capabilities section of your app so the app cannot be signed when built.

```
/Users/sirapol/Desktop/FirstCareFrontEnd/care_now_frontend_v1/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/shared_preferences/shared_prefe
    rences.framework: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
    Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    ...
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team
    ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

To fix this open the iOS project for the app in xcode, and select the Runner Target. You should see a **Signing & Capabilities** settings section where you can manage signing for the app, and **select a team for the project**. There will also be a button for creating a team if you do not have one already.

As for the Architecture errors:

```
warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings
    are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings
    are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
```

Setting the **deployment target to iOS 9.0** and above in the **General** section should fix this, and in general I would suggest making that the minimum iOS target for new flutter applications to help with package compatability unless you have a reason to support iOS 8.0.

And while not related to your issue but a future potential issue, I would change the `<false/>` to a `<string>` description under **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** as that is what is expected there:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to your device's location</string>
```